# left-align inside md-button

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I left-align elements inside a `md-button`? Sample code:

```
<md-button>
    <div md-ink-ripple layout="row">
        <div class="inset">
            <ng-md-icon icon="info"></ng-md-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="inset">
            Title
        </div>
    </div>
</md-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to override the CSS property `text-align:center` by `text-align:left` of `md-button`

Here the result on the MD Demo Page :

[image: button]

Comment: CitizenDelta, the <md-button> is a directive, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this style element:

```
<md-button md-no-ink="" class="md-primary" align="center" style="left:712px";>
    Search
</md-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**css**

Give you html some id first

```
<ng-md-icon id="SomeID" icon="info"></ng-md-icon>
```

Then in your css do

```
#SomeID{
  text-align:left;
}
```

that should sort you out.